# What depencencies are needed for JerseyTest

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey

I would like to run tests for my rest api but when running the Test class, I receive a NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/process/JerseyProcessingUncaughtExceptionHandler

So I added the dependency org.glassfish.jersey.core, jersey-common. Then I received another NoClassDefFoundError for another class and I had to set another dependecy and now again and again. Is there a depedency that solves all these problems or do I have to use 10+ dependencies to use the JerseyTest Framework. I slowly start to think that its better to not use it at all

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8080</port>
                <path>/</path>
                <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Please post the dependencies you are currently using and I can tell you what you need to get it working

Comment: ah right, i forgot this. I edited my originalpost. Also I removed the newly added dependencies since they didnt help at all.

Comment: Your jaxrs-ri is different version from the other Jersey deps. Fix that, and it probably should work. Also you should only have the test depdency in a test scope (but not the problem here)

Comment: amazing, now itworks! I didnt know that they have to be the on the same version. And do you mean there should be a separate pom.xml in the test folder?

Comment: No, `<scope>test</scope>` for the `<dependency>`s that are only used for testing. This way the test jars don't get added to the deployment build